# How to substitute }{ with },{ with gsub

Tags: awk, gsub

I am trying to replace the string `}{` with `},{` using `awk` and `gsub`.

My attempt is:

```
cat blobs.txt | awk '{gsub(/\\}\\{/,"},{"); print}' >> blobsDone.txt
```

I have read somewhere that characters like brackets need two backslashes to get matched but is not working. Can someone help me with it? I am getting crazy.

Comment: Refer this few articles : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520816/replacing-the-char-using-awk

Comment: Or this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118839/gsub-partial-replace

Comment: What do you want, from `}{` to `},{` or the other way round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it directly

```
sed -i 's/}{/},{/g' blobsDone.txt
```

Looks for `}{` and replaces by `},{` any time it is found in blobsDone.txt. The file is updated with new content.

If you do not want the file to be updated, just delete the `-i` parameter.

Incase it is `},{` to `}{`:

```
sed -i 's/},{/}{/g' blobsDone.txt
```

Comment: The OP wanted it the other way round `},{`-> `}{` so you might want to fix that ;-) but other than that I agree, the right tool here would be `sed`.

Comment: It is funny because I focused on the title of the question. Then in the text he/she says the opposite and in the code it is like I do. I will ask him to know : ) Anyway, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! How do I specify the input file if not with cat? And then, I just realised that I have a space between the two brackets. How do I match it?

Comment: @user2343163, sed gets it. It is the same `cat file | sed something` than `sed something file`.

Comment: Sorry I was looking for this:

    }{-> },{

Comment: @fedorqui I didn't even see that, apologies :-)

Comment: No problem, @AdrianFrühwirth, it was good to fix this ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! You were really kind! Do you also know how to match a whitespace? Because I just realised that I have a whitespace between the two brackets. I tried with 
    sed -i 's/}\s{/},{/g' blobs.txt
but it's not working yet.

Comment: In that case it would be `sed -i 's/} {/},{/g' blobsDone.txt`. If your question is answered, tick this answer or Ed Morton's so it is clear your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{gsub(/}{/,"},{"); print}' blobs.txt >> blobsDone.txt
```

wrt to "I have read somewhere that characters like brackets need two backslashes" - google regular expressions and in particular regular expression metacharacters and get the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition By Arnold Robbins, http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/awkprog3/.