# Ruby to replace contents of file between two markers

Tags: ruby

Trying to do like [Replace content in a file between two markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841089/replace-content-in-a-file-between-two-markers) but the accepted answer doesn't seem to be working:

**index.html**

```
<!--start-->Hello world<!--end-->
```

**myscript.rb**

```
def replace(file_path, contents)
    file = File.open(file_path, "r+")
    html = ""

    while(!file.eof?)
        html += file.readline
    end

    file.close()

    return html.gsub(/<!--start-->(.*)<!--end-->/im, contents)
end

thing = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"].sample

replace("/path/to/index.html", thing)
```

After running `ruby myscript.rb`, `index.html` remains the same. I'm on Ruby 2.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing you script as follows:

```
def replace(file_path, contents)
  content = File.read(file_path)
  new_content = content.gsub(/(<!--start-->)(.*)(<!--end-->)/im, "\\1#{contents}\\3")

  File.open(file_path, "w+") { |file| file.puts new_content }
  new_content
end

thing = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"].sample

replace("./my_file", thing)
```

For working with files - check this [great tutorial](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/io/)!

Good luck!

Comment: Your method looks a lot better, but unfortunately the index file remains the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: @FlyntHamlock - You are absolutely right! I've just updated my answer! (plus some shorter syntax is used). Apologies for confusion!

Comment: Awesome - thanks! Is there a way to not remove the `<!--start-->` and `<!--end-->` though?

Comment: @FlyntHamlock - Sure you can! Check my answer updated! (also, take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118839/gsub-partial-replace)). Good luck!

Comment: Absolutely gorgeous! Thanks again!